# How to reverse tree-like linkages in a set?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have a python script that is parsing a block of data and creating a set of objects.  These objects are instances of a class that has an identifier and a list of other identifiers.  The identifiers are strings, if it matters.  The data is similar to a directory tree, but one that has many symbolic links.  The problem is that the symbolic links only go one way, down the tree.  I need to be able to look at the bottom id and say what links to it.  I can't find a good explanation of the algorithm to do this that would easily translate into my python script (mainly because I'm not a python programmer, I normally use C).

Here's a sample dataset:

```
Obj1: id=1, lnk=[3,5,7,9]
Obj2: id=2, lnk=[4,9]
Obj3: id=3, lnk=[4,8,9]
Obj4: id=4, lnk=[6,7]
Obj5: id=5, lnk=[2]
...
my_set = set(Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, Obj4, Obj5, ...)
```

Read these as "1 is using 3, 5, 7, and 9", "2 is using 4 and 9", etc.

I need to be able to output either:

```
9 is used by [1,2,3]
8 is used by [3]
7 is used by [1,4]
6 is used by [4]
5 is used by [1]
4 is used by [2,3]
3 is used by [1]
2 is used by [5]
```

or (these are sets, not tuples):

```
9 is used by (1,2,3,5)
8 is used by (1,3)
7 is used by (1,2,3,4,5)
6 is used by (1,2,3,4,5)
5 is used by (1)
4 is used by (1,2,3,5)
3 is used by (1)
2 is used by (1,5)
```

The first seems simpler to get, but the second is what I really want.

Comment: Could you include sample code that would create the tree?

Comment: The dataset I'm showing is the tree data parsed into the structures I'm using.  The code to generate that dataset isn't relevant to the problem, and is pretty long and involved and wouldn't help the issue..

Comment: I've posted an answer but I'm not sure I'm fully understanding what you need - please could you explain why the two result sets are showing different results? Or are you just asking how to return tuples instead of lists?

Comment: @JonS: yes it would because then someone could write a few lines of code to produce that outcome. Now we can only wave hands.

Comment: The second results has done further processing to go all the way back up the tree so it's showing everything above it that is using it, rather than just the one level above it.  For example, 2 is used by 5, but 5 is used by 1, so 2 is being used by 5 directly, and 1 indirectly.

Comment: @SimeonVisser Yes, I want those few lines of code.  The input dataset I'm showing has already been processed a lot to get it to be that simple.  I'm looking for the next step in the process to get me to the final output I need.  That hand-waving can't be done earlier in the process.

Comment: @JonS: you do see that this question is much easier to answer when someone has a (simplified) tree object, as constructed by you, in their Python shell to write the lines that generate your desired outcome?

Comment: @SimeonVisser If you answered "how do I create the tree object?" then you would have answered the question I'm asking.  I'm not asking how to print the data.

Comment: Sorry - I understand now -- you need the "linked items" AND any that are linked by association - I have deleted my erroneous answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you code the objects like this:

```
Obj1 = {1: [3,5,7,9]}
Obj2 = {2: [4,9]}
...
```

then you can combine them all into a single dictionary:

```
my_objs = {1: [3,5,7,9], 2: [4,9], ...}
```

Now you can create the reverse tree like this:

```
tree = {}
for id, lnks in my_objs.items():
    for lnk in lnks:
        uplnks = tree.get(lnk, [])
        uplnks.append(id)
        tree[lnk] = uplnks
```

Finally, you can print the tree:

```
def used_by(tree, id, all_lnks=None):
    if all_lnks is None:
        all_lnks = set()
    lnks = tree.get(id)
    if not lnks:
        return all_lnks
    all_lnks.update(lnks)
    for lnk in lnks:
        all_lnks = used_by(tree, lnk, all_lnks)
    return all_lnks

for id in tree.keys():
    print id, 'is used by', list(used_by(tree, id))
```

Comment: My objects are a little more complicated, so I should be able to create my_objs as a dictionary of arbitrary numbers mapped to the Obj1, Obj2, etc., right?  And just modify your code to go a level into the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is add a new instance variable to your custom object type called something like `upstream`, which is initialized to `None`.

Then start at the root of the tree and recursively follow the links down, in a depth-first traversal, appending each new link as you go to a running list and populating the upstream for each to a copy of the running list.  When you hit nodes that already have `upstream` set to `not None` you can avoid recursing.

Comment: If there isn't a single root, can I just iterate through the set?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think that will work to get the full list of upstream dependencies as it would short-circuit when it hits a node where `upstream` is already populated, and then would miss upstream dependencies.  Is your data a tree or a graph?  Or is it a forest?

Comment: It's a group of subversion repos and I'm parsing the externals.  I suppose I can do one repo at a time and that will give me a single root.  I had just been hoping to do all the repos together.

Comment: The other problem is that there aren't any actual links in the data, it's "linked" only because they are the same id (numbers in my example here, strings in my real data).

Comment: when you parse it, you could make it a link of actual objects though right? Or you could always create a `dict` mapping id to the actual object or hash your objs based on id